# How to correctly exclude hidden files and directories in linux `grep` result?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, grep, gnu

I'm trying to exclude hidden files and directories in [grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) command.

I found some answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158639/158547) but they're not working:

```bash
grep -r --color=always -n -H --exclude-dir='.*' -- 'something'
```

The reason is that `grep` will output things like:

```bash
./README.md:178:Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
./README.md:179:Plug 'linrongbin16/fzfx.nvim'
./README.md:183:lua require('fzfx').setup()
./README.md:194:    use { "junegunn/fzf", run = ":call fzf#install()" }
```

They all start with `./`, so if simply set `--exclude-dir='.*'`, that will exclude all outputs.

Would you please help me with correct `grep` command?

Comment: Why the tags `ripgrep`, `rg`? if you are just using `grep`?

Comment: There is not hidden file in your example. It's not clear to me which files exactly you want to exclude. All files in the working directory?

Comment: Please try something like `find . -type f -name ".*" -prune -o -type f -exec grep --color=always -n -H "something" {} \;`.

Comment: @tshiono That's good but why did you use `\;` instead of `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the command you wrote doesn't start every filename with a `./`. If you add a dot in the end, i.e. `-- 'something' .`, then it does. Anyway, you can either do:

```bash
grep -r --color=always -n -H --exclude-dir='.*' -- 'something' "$PWD"
```

Or:

```bash
grep -r --color=always -n -H --exclude-dir='.?*' -- 'something'
```

Side note, are you sure you want `--exclude-dir` and not `--exclude`?

Comment: I found the reason is that I am using macOS builtin grep, it's a bsd grep not gnu grep. that is the root cause.